# Rails db fields not updating properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, models

I'm trying to write get increment/decrement methods working for a fairly simple class and im running into a strange issue.  If i call give_point(), points get incremented to 1, then calling it over and over again nothing happens. Then if i all give_dm(), points gets reset to 0 and dms gets set to 1... I can't get it to keep incrementing and they keep resetting each other in my database.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have no idea what's wrong and I've been staring at this for quite some time now.  Thanks for any help ahead of time!

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    validates :content, :presence => true
    after_initialize :init

    def init
        self.points = 0
        self.dms = 0
    end


    def give_point()
        self.points += 1
        update(points: self.points)
    end

    def take_point()
        self.point -= 1
        update(points: self.points)
    end

    def give_dm()
        self.dms += 1
        update(dms: self.dms)
    end

    def take_dm()
        self.dms -= 1
        update(dms: self.dms)
    end

end
```

Comment: You're doing `after_initialize :init` ... are you `find`ing the record between calls to `give` and `take`?  And if you have the same `after_initialize` in the `User` model then the user record will also get initialized to zeros on every `.find` (including the `.find`s your doing in the `Post` model).

Comment: Were you aware that `after_initialize` is called every time a record is instantiated?  That's with `new` and also with any db retrieval.  You might want to do `self.points = 0 if new_record?` and ditto with the dms column... so it doesn't happen when you're retrieving an existing record.

Comment: Ah, cool.  Let me put it into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after_initialize` is called every time a record is instantiated... this means both new records but also with any db retrievals.

If you only want to initialize for new records, you may want to change the init method...

```
def init
  self.points = 0 if new_record?
  self.dms = 0 if new_record?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The init functions gets called every time, so your attributes are set to 0.
From ruby docs:

```
after_find and after_initialize callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with after_initialize being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html